# Cannot boot Ubuntu 10.04 from USB

Tags: boot, usb

I tried to install Ubuntu 10.04 from my Silicon Power 4gb pendrive.I currently have installed Ubuntu 11.10.

I downloaded "ubuntu-10.04.4-desktop-i386" from Ubuntu's site and created an USB bootable drive using the instructions from the site.

When I insert my usb to boot it gives the following error:

```
unknown keyword in configuration file: gfxboot
vesamenu.c32: not a COM32R image
boot:
```

Please, can you give me any solution?

Answer (score 2):

When you encounter the above error, simply hit <kbd>tab</kbd>, then you will be shown certain options like `live`, `install` etc.

Type `live` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.Hopefully this should solve your problem.

Let me know if it worked !!  :)

Answer (score 0):

Type `live` at the prompt and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

You will get into the Live session from where you can install

Answer (score 0):

Typing

```
live
```

didn't work for me at this point, but typing

```
help
```

did. This bug seems most thoroughly discussed here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/usb-creator/+bug/645818

Hope posting this workaround here might help someone else resolve this a bit quicker that I did!

Answer (score 0):

unknown keyword in configuration file: gfxboot
vesamenu.c32: not a COM32R image
boot:

This above problem can be solve as follows:

When you encounter the above error, simply hit <kbd>tab</kbd>, then you will be shown certain options like live, install etc.

Type live or install and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Answer (score -1):

Looks like the data on the drive was not written correctly or is corrupt. Try erasing everything on the drive, and then re-creating the bootable USB drive. If that doesn't work, you could try the LiveCD option (Instructions at http://www.ubuntu.com/download/ubuntu/download). Hope this helps!